# How to remove specific group from a plot but plot stays the same in R?

Tags: r, plot, grouping, pca

```
data('iris')
pca.irix <- PCA(iris[ ,1:4])
gg <- factoextra::fviz_pca_biplot(X = pca.irix, 
                             # samples
                             fill.ind = iris$Species, col.ind = 'black',
                             pointshape = 21, pointsize = 1.5,
                             geom.ind = 'point', repel = T,
                             geom.var = FALSE )
```

I would like to obtain a plot that is exactly like the plot above but without the specie `setosa`.
I started doing this, but do not know how to continue

```
setosa_wo <- iris %>% 
             filter(Species != 'setosa')

gg + scale_x_continuous(limits = c((-2), 2)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c((-2), 2))
```

How to remove a colored group from a plot? But the plot should stay the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to remove one or any number of groups from the plot would be to filter the data used for the layers, e.g. having a look at `gg$layers` show that your PCA plot is composed of six layers, however only in the first two of the layers are the groups used as fill color. Therefore I simply filtered the data for these two layers which gives me a plot where `setosa` is removed.

**EDIT** Following the suggestion by **@DaveArmstrong** I added his code to fix the ranges of the axes on the original ranges and addtionally added the original colors

```r
library(FactoMineR)
library(ggplot2)

pca.irix <- PCA(iris[ ,1:4])

gg <- factoextra::fviz_pca_biplot(X = pca.irix, 
                                  # samples
                                  fill.ind = iris$Species, col.ind = 'black',
                                  pointshape = 21, pointsize = 1.5,
                                  geom.ind = 'point', repel = T,
                                  geom.var = FALSE )

# First: Get the ranges
yrg <- ggplot2::layer_scales(gg)$y$range$range
xrg <- ggplot2::layer_scales(gg)$x$range$range

# Filter the data
gg$layers[[1]]$data <- dplyr::filter(gg$layers[[1]]$data, Fill. != "setosa")
gg$layers[[2]]$data <- dplyr::filter(gg$layers[[2]]$data, Fill. != "setosa")

gg + 
  # Set the limits to the original ones
  ggplot2::coord_cartesian(xlim=xrg, ylim=yrg, expand=FALSE) +
  # Add orignial colors
  ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = scales::hue_pal()(3)[2:3])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think in addition to the good answer above, the OP wanted to maintain the original x- and y-axis limits.  You could do that by modifying the above (the x- and y- ranges have to be calculated before the data are filtered): 
`yrg <- layer_scales(gg)$y$range$range`,
`xrg <- layer_scales(gg)$x$range$range`,
`gg + coord_cartesian(xlim=xrg, ylim=yrg, expand=FALSE)`

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Hi Dave. Thanks for your suggestion. I have added it to my answer and by the way also fixed the fill colors. Best S.